# Use variables as object elment name

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to do something like this;

```
var fieldName = 'name';
if ((await db.friends.where({ ${fieldName}: 'Josephine'}).count()) === 0) {
        const id = await db.friends.add({name: "Josephine", age: 21});
        alert (`Addded friend with id ${id}`);
    }
```

Is the any way to do this thing in Javascript?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you have to use `[]`:

```
var fieldName = 'name';
if ((await db.friends.where({ [fieldName]: 'Josephine'}).count()) === 0) {
    const id = await db.friends.add({name: "Josephine", age: 21});
    alert (`Addded friend with id ${id}`);
}
```

Comment: (I dont know the use case and background, BUT be aware of SQL injection possibilities if you do stuff like this. If you can, use an allow-list for the fieldNames - if your ORM does not prevent this automatically)